# OCaml map not updating before the next step in a sequence

Tags: dictionary, recursion, ocaml

I am trying to implement a basic parser, scanner, and a minimal language in OCaml.  I *believe* the issue is that I'm trying to maintain a map between variables in this toy language and their values, and the language should be able to handle an expression like `a=2;a` and return 2.  The name seems to successfully store the number 2, but by the time the program moves on to evaluating the second expression, it does not find the name in the map.  And I can't understand why.

Below is the abstract syntax tree.

**Ast.ml**

```
type operator = Add (* for now just one operator *)

type expr =
    Binop of expr * operator * expr
  | Lit of int                      (* a number *)
  | Seq of expr * expr              (* a sequence, to behave like ";" *)
  | Asn of string * expr            (* assignment, to behave like "=" in an imperative language *)
  | Var of string                   (* a variable *)
```

Here are the parser and scanner.

**parser.mly**

```
%{ 
open Ast 
%}

%token SEQ PLUS ASSIGN EOF
%token <int> LITERAL
%token <string> VARIABLE

%left SEQ PLUS 

%start expr
%type <Ast.expr> expr

%%

expr:
| expr SEQ expr        { Seq($1, $3) }
| expr PLUS   expr { Binop($1, Add, $3) }
| LITERAL          { Lit($1) }
| VARIABLE         { Var($1) }
| VARIABLE ASSIGN expr { Asn($1, $3) }
```

**scanner.mll**

```
{ 
open Parser 
}

rule tokenize = parse
  [' ' '\t' '\r' '\n'] { tokenize lexbuf }
| '+' { PLUS }
| ['0'-'9']+ as lit { LITERAL(int_of_string lit) }
| ['a'-'z']+ as id { VARIABLE(id) }
| '=' { ASSIGN }
| ';' { SEQ }
| eof { EOF }
```

And here's where I tried to implement a sort of name-space in a basic calculator.

**calc.ml**

```
open Ast

module StringMap = Map.Make(String)
let namespace = ref StringMap.empty

let rec eval exp = match exp with  
  | Lit(n) -> n        
  | Binop(e1, op, e2) ->
      let v1 = eval e1 in
      let v2 = eval e2 in
      v1+v2
  | Asn (name, e) -> 
      let v = eval e in 
      (namespace := StringMap.add name v !namespace; v)
  | Var(name) -> StringMap.find name !namespace
  | Seq(e1, e2) -> 
      (let _ = eval e1 in 
      eval e2)

let _ =
  let lexbuf = Lexing.from_channel stdin in
  let expr = Parser.expr Scanner.tokenize lexbuf in
  let result = eval expr in
  print_endline (string_of_int result)
```

To test it out I compile, and it compiles successfully, then run `$ ./calc` in a terminal, and enter `a=2;a` then press `Ctrl+D`.  It should print 2 but it gives a `Not found` exception.  Presumably this is coming from the `StringMap.find` line, and it's not finding the name in the namespace.  I've tried throwing print lines around, and I think I can confirm that the sequence is being correctly processed in the terminal and that the first evaluation is happening successfully, with the name and value getting entered into the string map.  But for some reason it seems not to be there when the program moves on to processing the second expression in the sequence.

I'd appreciate any clarification, thanks.

Comment: The `eval` function seems to work fine when I execute `let expr = Seq(Asn("a", Lit(2)), Var("a")) in eval expr;;`

Comment: A couple of suggestions: if you're using `Map` but want mutable state, you may want `Hashtbl`. If you want to avoid mutable state, you could pass a namespace as an argument to `eval`. This may be especially helpful if you implement grouping with parens/braces/brackets and the idea of scoping.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your error.
Feeding the AST directly to `eval`

```ml
let () =
  let ast = Seq(Asn ("a", Lit 2),Var "a") in
  let result = eval ast in
  print_endline (string_of_int result)
```

prints `2` as expected.

After fixing your parser to recognize the end of the stream:

```
entry:
| expr EOF { $1 }
```

using it in

```
let () =
  let s = Lexing.from_string "a=2;a\n" in
  let ast = Parser.entry Scanner.tokenize s in
  let result = eval ast in
  print_endline (string_of_int result)
```

prints `2` as expected. And without this fix, your code fails with a syntax error.

EDIT:
Rather than using a makefile, I will advise to use dune, with the following simple `dune` file:

```
(menhir (modules parser))
(ocamllex scanner)
(executable (name calc))
```

it will at least solve your compilation troubles.

Comment: Interesting.  I had a typo in my original code, I wonder if that was responsible for the syntax error.  When I compile it now, I don't get such an error.  I added the fix for the EOF, but still when I run this through the terminal it has the unexplained behavior.  Do you think there something strange happening with lexbuf or something like that?

Comment: You should avoid using the terminal for your test and use a string input to make your issue more reproducible. Currently, from the information available in your question, your code works as expected.

Comment: Ok, so when I try to do it this way, when I compile the compilation just hangs (doing it from a make file).  When I individually compile the parser it's fine, but now when I compile the scanner it says the first line is a syntax error (the `{ open Parser }` line).  Since I'm still using things that I pretty completely don't understand, I'm not sure what's going on here.  I would guess that since the scanner uses lexbuf and that seems to be gone in your code, that's somehow the source of the problem.

Comment: I don't really get what the parser and scanner do, and it's a little confusing how the scanner can refer to something in `calc.ml` which isn't open in the scanner file, that's pretty weird.  So I'm just guessing at why it has the behavior it does.

Comment: (You don't need to open a module to refer to it. Using `open` is just a convenience to avoid repeating the module name. Uses of `open` should be kept to a minimum in fact to avoid filling up the local namespace.)

Comment: @JeffreyScofield when I delete that line it now gives the exception `Error: Unbound constructor PLUS`.

Comment: You need to fully qualify (for instance `Ast.Plus`) the ast constructors in `eval` if you remove `open Ast`.

Comment: (I'm not saying to remove `open` I'm saying it's not surprising that you can access a modle without opening it.)

Comment: I see, so I'm going to leave the `open` part then.  But still the code does not compile.

Comment: Oh I should also note that I only recently realized that I was misunderstanding one part of the code here.  I thought the EOF part was intended to just get tacked to the end of the `expr` thing.  I now realize that was intended to be a new thing called `entry`.  However, I'm working with an .mli file that I cannot edit, and it depends on `expr` using `lexbuf`.  So it seems that given these conditions, I have to do this through the command line.

Comment: Going through the command line or not doesn't matter. You still have a end-of-stream conflict with your `expr` parser entry. And if you are not getting a syntax error, it might be possible that you are using a stale executable, which would explain why your error is not reproducible. It doesn't matter that your homework require a fixed mli file for the parser, you should delete it for now and try to fix your code.

Comment: I'm trying to fix the code, I just don't know how.  Anyway, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Hey so I don't know if you are still looking for the solution, but I was able to reproduce the problem and how I solved it was simply adding assign to the %left statement in parser.mly

`%left SEQ ASSIGN PLUS`